# How to put Lisp/Scheme/Racket symbol at the end?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, lisp, racket, infix-notation

A form in Lisp/Scheme/Racket has symbol put at first position. This code works in Racket:

```
(define (? a b) (if a (display b) 0))
(? #t "Hello")
```

But I want to simulate the `a? b:0` statement in C/C++ and the question mark (the symbol) is supposed to be at the end, after `a`.

**How to put `?` and `a` and `b` in this order?**

```
(define (a ? b) (if a (display b) 0))
(#t ? "Hello")
```

Do I need to use `define-syntax` or that kind of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me offer an alternative solution via overriding the application syntax [`#%app`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/application.html). Here's an example of the ternary operator in C-like languages:

```
#lang racket

(require syntax/parse/define
         (only-in racket [#%app racket:#%app]))

(define-syntax-parser #%app
  [(_ test-expr {~datum ?} then-expr {~datum :} else-expr)
   #'(if test-expr then-expr else-expr)]
  [(_ xs ...)
   #'(racket:#%app xs ...)])
```

```
> ((= 42 42) ? "a" : "b")
"a"
> ((= 42 0) ? "a" : "b")
"b"
```

Because the application syntax has the lowest priority, other syntax will be considered first:

```
> (define-simple-macro (discard-all xs ...) 1)
> (discard-all ? 42 : 123)
1
> (if ? 1 : 2)
if: bad syntax ;; because if should have exactly three subforms, but the above line has four.
```

But as Ryan said, this is not a "good" Racket code in a sense that it defies Racket convention and no one (well, probably except you) will be able to understand your code.

Comment: tks, this is the syntax i wanted to have

Comment: error "module: duplicate definition for identifier" when i try to define the second syntax using define-syntax-parser

Comment: i found it out how, can't use define-syntax-parser twice, put all syntax in the same `define-syntax-parser` block

Answer (score 3):

I have three answers to your question.

## 1 Don't do that

Every language has rules, conventions, and pragmatics. Your Racket experience will be painful if you try to force it to look like C/C++. You will waste time on issues like this instead of learning to think in the Racket programming model and use the tools that Racket has developed around that model.

For a specific example, Racket has the rule that a form (an expression, definition, declaration, etc) starts with the *operator* (like `display` or `list` or `+`) or *syntactic keyword* (like `define` or `if`). That rule eliminates lots of complicated problems that get in the way of extensible syntax. For example, what would be the priority of infix syntax vs other special forms; in `(lambda ? 5)`, is that a `lambda` form or a (bad) `?` form?

To clarify: Racket absolutely encourages you to extend the language with new syntactic forms, within the bounds of S-expression, operator-first syntax.

## 2 A partial solution

Racket's reader has a limited form of support for "infix syntax". If you put dots around a single term in a parenthesized group, the reader moves the enclosed term to the front. So the following two terms are treated the same by the reader:

```
(1 . < . 2)
(< 1 2)
```

So you could write

```
(#t . ? . "Hello")
```

Personally, I think this usually makes code harder to read.

## 3 An open research topic

People are doing research on extending Racket's language-building framework to work nicely with non-S-expression-based syntaxes. One example is Honu; see the paper ["Honu: Syntactic Extension for Algebraic Notation through Enforestation](https://www.cs.utah.edu/plt/publications/gpce12-rf.pdf). There are others, and the topic is still open.

Comment: one could imagine using special kind of parens to indicate such infix-allowing contexts. like e.g. `{language_name ...... <language code> .... }`. this would make it unambiguous.

Comment: tks, i know it's spoiling the rule but just trying it out :)